# IOS Subscription Policy field

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, unity-game-engine, subscription

I have implemented **in-app subscription** into my app(**created with Unity3D**) but got rejected Apple Review Team. The reason is that user can't understand subscription type("non-autorenewal" or "autorenewal").
After that I have checked other apps to find out the way that they introducing subscription plans and found this(check the image).

**Now my question is, how can I add "Policy" field into my in-app purchase?**

Tried to find it in Appstoreconnect Connect, in Info.plist, in product creating script, but no luck.
Also I think is it configurable with Swift code, but unfortunately my app is made with Unity3D.

[image]